# Tkinter importing without *?

Tags: python, tkinter

In my past programming i used the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
Gui = Tk()
```

but someone told me that importing * was not good for many reasons but now when i want to import

```
from tkinter import geometry
```

it says geometry not a module thing (name).

and when i do:

```
    import tkinter 
tkinter.geometry(500x500)
```

it says 'module' object has no attribute 'geometry'

Can someone explain me how to import with tkinter all the different ways?? Not only for geometry but most of the tkinter modules...???

Comment: there is no `geometry` in `tkinter`, no matter what import you use. Are you actually meaning `Gui.geometry` (`tkinter.Tk.geometry`)?

Comment: Actually, `from tkinter import *` is considered ok, even though it contradicts PEP8, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48746351/tkinter-documentation-is-contradicting-pep8/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tkinter documentation is contradicting PEP8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48746351/tkinter-documentation-is-contradicting-pep8)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's because the **module** `tkinter` doesn't have a `geometry` function.  It's the `Tk` instances that do.

Here's a good way to accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
import tkinter as tk     # tk is a convenient, easy to type alias to use for tkinter.
gui = tk.Tk()
gui.geometry("500x500")   # don't forget the quotes
```

### Why `from tkinter import *` is a non-ideal way to import tkinter

As an aside, whoever told you that `from tkinter import *` was a bad idea was correct - when you do that, you load all of tkinter's namespace into your module's namespace.

If you do that, you can end up with unpleasant namespace collisions, like this:

```
from tkinter import *
gui = Tk()
Label = "hello"
Label1 = Label(gui, text=Label)

# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "stackoverflow.py", line 98, in <module>
#     Label1 = Label(gui, text=Label)
# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

You've **overwritten** the reference to tkinter's `Label` widget - so you can't create any more Labels!  Of course you shouldn't be capitalizing local variables like that anyways, but why worry about avoiding those namespace problems when you can do this instead:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

This ^^^^ import method is also preferable because if at some point you want to swap Tkinter out for another module with a similar implementation, instead of combing through your code for all elements of the Tkinter module, you can just go like this:

```
#import tkinter as tk
import newTkinter as tk
```

And you're all set.  Or, if you want to use another module that happens to have some of the same names for its classes and methods, the following would cause chaos:

```
from tkinter import *
from evilOverlappingModule import *
```

but this would be fine:

```
import tkinter as tk
import evilOverlappingModule as evil
```

Comment: personally I would advise to use `... as tk` rather than `... as TK`, simply because `TK` looks more like a class name than a module name, and it's more obtrusive.

Comment: A bit late, but I agree. Swapped in tk for TK.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that `from module import *` is considered harmful is that it pollutes the main namespace with every public name in the module. At best this makes code less explicit, at worst, it can cause name collisions. For example, module `codecs` has an `open` method defined, and there is the built-in version, which take different arguments. If I write

```
from codecs import *
f = open(…)
```

which `open` will I get? Tkinter has a *lot* of symbols, and tkinter based programs tend to use them very heavily. better than the `import *` is

```
import tkinter as tk
```

which then allows the — still explicit, but easier to type and read:

```
tk.Tk().geometry(…)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you `*` imported tkinter, essentially `tkinter.` is in the namespace, meaning that to access to tkinter modules without worrying about prefixing it with `tkinter.`. In this case, `geometry("500x500")` is a method of `Tk()`, so you would use it like this

```
from Tkinter import *

Gui = Tk()
Gui.geometry("500x500")
Gui.mainloop()
```

Similar objects, such as various widgets, etc. are used the same. For example, a label would be made like this:

```
from Tkinter import *

Gui = Tk()
label= Label(Gui, text="Hello World!")
label.pack()

Gui.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why someone said that importing * wasn't good cause that isn't true, it's actually better then just importing tkinter. Importing `*` will make the programming easier. With just tkinter you would need to type `tkinter.` before doing something, or if you do it as tk, you would need to do `tk.`, `from tkinter import *` is the best what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing:

```
from tkinter import *
```

You can do:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas #The widgets you want to use
```

Or:

```
import tkinter as tk
```

Comment: from tkinter import * and from tkinter import Tk will make the programming easier because you don't have to do   tk.Button, you can just do Button

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a quick answer: Tkinter doesn’t have a geometry function. You can use the geometry function with instances of the Tk() class.
Example:

```
import tkinter as tk # Use the module name ’Tkinter’ if you have Python 2
root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry(‘500x500’) # You can change the size 

# Other code goes here

root.mainloop()
```

Just like the geometry function, the mainloop, pack, grid, place, config etc. functions are used with the instances of the class Tk()

Thank You! Hope that works!