# Please explain rationale for tkinter global import approach

Tags: python, tkinter

This is a basic question, so I apologize if it has come up before. I searched stackoverflow and elsewhere, but I could not find a definitive answer.

I am curious why tkinter examples typically use a global import approach. Even the Python documentation states this is the more common method of use:

> ...to use Tkinter, all you need to do is to import one module:
>
> ```
> import Tkinter
> ```
>
> Or, more often:
>
> ```
> from Tkinter import *
> ```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html

I thought global imports are generally frowned upon? Assuming that is true, there must be a good reason to use the global import in this case. Can someone please enlighten me?

EDIT:
After posting the question (and receiving several helpful replies - thanks!), I also found the following helpful thread:
[Tkinter importing without *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337882/tkinter-importing-without?rq=1)

Comment: It saves you from having to type the "Tkinter." all along your code...

Comment: Generally you don't want to pollute the global namespace with the global import, but practicality beats purity.

Comment: I hope you don't take the answers as a reason to code this way. There may be a reason why some documentation says to do it, but I would argue that none of those reasons are good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, global imports are generally frowned upon for various reasons. However, a Tkinter program is going to use a lot of Tkinter functionality, so the global import is seen as a time-saver by a lot of developers. It is assumed that name collisions will be rare, since you're unlikely to be defining your own GUI classes and whatnot that would need similar names. If you were, you wouldn't use the global import.

And Tkinter (and a lot if its example code) dates back to the twentieth century, so it does not necessarily adhere to PEP 8, which is very much a twenty-first century document.

A modern compromise would be to `import Tkinter as tk` and then use `tk.Button` and the like. This is easier to type than `tkinter.Button` but a lot clearer than just `Button`, especially if you are writing software to run a button factory.

Comment: You say nam collisions are rare, but I see name collisions on this site a lot. For example, both the tkinter and ttk packages have a class named `Button`, and these two modules are frequently used together.

Comment: I say *it is assumed* that name collisions will be rare... and we know what happens to programmers who assume. :-)

Answer (score 1):

When you write a GUI application, you use its API very intensively, unlike anything else. Buttons, text entries, events and many many more. It's simply very practical to just import everything.