# Zen of Python: "Special cases aren’t special enough to break the rules"

Tags: python

I can't find a proper explanation of what is meant by the following two lines of the Zen of Python:

> Special cases aren’t special enough to break the rules.
>   Although practicality beats purity.

I found an example [here](http://artifex.org/~hblanks/talks/2011/pep20_by_example.html) but I don't quite understand it.

Can someone please explain what these statements refer to and provide an example?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/292/

Comment: [xkcd.com/1172](https://xkcd.com/1172/) may also be relevant  (though much less so than 292)

Answer (score 2):

I think PEP8 covers this [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#a-foolish-consistency-is-the-hobgoblin-of-little-minds):

> In particular: do not break backwards compatibility just to comply
>   with this PEP!

And here is an example from [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48746351/tkinter-documentation-is-contradicting-pep8) where `from tkinter import *` is considered ok by the Python developers even though it violates PEP 8 advice.

Comment: Let me unwrap the example to make sure that I fully understand it: since ```from tinker import *``` is practical, it's allowed to break the PEP8 advice. However, I still don't understand what the first line refers to. Can you give an example for a "special case" that "breaks the rules" and how it should rather be handled?

Comment: I think your conclusion is wrong (or at least unclear). If you're starting to write new code, you shouldn't use `from tkinter import *`. This has nothing to do with backwards compatibility. I do agree that if you have existing code, it doesn't necessarily make sense to refactor it to use a proper import.

Comment: @BryanOakley well i know you don't agree, but I'm pretty much quoting the python devs from issue 3280, and they don't want to change the docs so `from tkinter import *` is still officially recommended

Comment: The docs don't actually say to use the wildcard import. In fact, they start by showing the proper way, before stating many people do it the other way. It's a real pity that they chose to give examples that go against their very guidelines. <shrug> The import thing to remember is that the goal isn't to mimic the documentation, but rather to write good code. PEP8 has proven to be a valuable resource in helping you to write good code.