# NameError: name 'tkinter' is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter, nameerror

so i tried to work with tkinter and i got this error on a very simple code could you help me?

the code:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
l1 = tkinter.Label(window, text = "exmple text" , font = ("Arial" , 14))
l1.grid(row =0 ,column = 0 , sticky = E)
window.mainloop()
```

the error i get:

```
NameError: name 'tkinter' is not defined
```

i dont know what am i missing because i saw pepole online that simple codes like this work for them

Comment: You didn't name your python file as `tkinter.py`,right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a little mistake made when you try to call Label from tkinter...

First of all, i'm gonna proceed to put the correct code and then i'll explain some details about it:

```
from tkinter import *
window = Tk()
l1 = Label(window, text = "exmple text" , font = ("Arial" , 14))
l1.grid(row =0 ,column = 0 , sticky = E)
window.mainloop()
```

Your mistake was that you tried to use

```
l1 = tkinter.Label(window, text = "exmple text" , font = ("Arial" , 14))
```

doing `from tkinter import *` you load all of tkinter's namespace into your module's namespace, so you can not call tkinter and the module again... instead, you just call the module.That's why your error was telling you have not defined tkinter.

Anyways, doing this type of import it's bad, cause you can make some silly mistakes and end up with unpleasant namespace collisions.

The right syntax and format would be an `import tkinter` and then call tkinter's function, just to prevent namespace collisions and loosing time by looking were did you fail.

You should checkout this question made some time ago to get more details about what i'm talking! [Tkinter importing without *?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18337882/tkinter-importing-without)

EDIT: Use this code, should work and you won't have to worry about namespace collision :)

```
import tkinter
window = tkinter.Tk()
l1 = tkinter.Label(window, text = "example text" , font = ("Arial" , 14))
l1.grid(row =0 ,column = 0 , sticky = tkinter.E)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is actually quite common to do `import tkinter as tk` on the code you added in the edit, resulting in shorter code.

Comment: thank you very much! your explanation made me to understand what i did wrong

Answer (score 1):

Just import tkinter like this:

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
l1 = tkinter.Label(window, text = "exmple text" , font = ("Arial" , 14))
l1.grid(row =0 ,column = 0 , sticky = tkinter.E)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: but now it giving me this error : NameError: name 'Tk' is not defined

Comment: Now it works. Just call the methods from the `tkinter` module with the dot operator.